# ASM call Printf

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler, att

```
movl %ebx, %esi
movl $.LC1, %edi
movl $0, %eax
call printf
```

I use the following asm code to print what is in *EBX* register. When I use

```
movl $1,%eax
int 0x80
```

and the `echo $?` I get the correct answer but segmentation fault in the first case. I am using the GNU Assembler and AT&T syntax. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: here .LC1: .string "%d\n"

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the code, you are probably in 64 bit mode (please confirm) in which case pointers are 64 bit in size.  In a position-depended executable on Linux `movl $.LC1, %edi` is safe and what compilers use, but to make your code position-independent and able to handle symbol addresses being outside the low 32 bits you can use `leaq .LC1(%rip), %rdi`.

Furthermore, make sure that:

- you are preserving value of `rbx` in your function
- stack pointer is aligned as required

This code works for me in 64 bit:

```
.globl main
main:
    push %rbx
    movl $42, %ebx
    movl %ebx, %esi
    leaq .LC1(%rip), %rdi
    movl $0, %eax
    call printf
    xor  %eax, %eax
    pop  %rbx
    ret

.data
    .LC1: .string "%d\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: As Jester noted, this answer only applies to x86 (32 bits) asm whereas the sample provided is more likely for x86-64.

That's because printf has a variable number of arguments. The printf call doesn't restore the stack for you, you need to do it yourself.

In your example, you'd need to write (32 bits assembly):

```
push %ebx
push $.LC1
call printf
add $8, %esp  // 8 : 2 argument of 4 bytes
```

Comment: Yes this is true in 32 bit mode, in which case he should put the arguments on the stack. But the code looks more like 64 bit, so your answer doesn't apply.

Comment: @Jester You're right. I assumed it was 32 bits because I only saw 32 bits registers and overlooked the calling convention itself (no argument in stack). I will make that appear in my answer.