# Perfect number C-NASM program not working?

Tags: c, assembly, numbers, nasm

so basically the program prints the factors of a number and checks if the inputted number is a perfect number. However, all the program does is ask for the input and then crashes. I assume that it has an endless loop somewhere in the .asm file. What could be the problem? Any and all suggestions/replies is appreciated. :)

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int factors(int a);

int main()
{
       int a1, x;

   ag: printf("Enter a number: ");
       scanf("%d", &a1);
       if(a1 >= 65536)
       {
           printf("Invalid number, Enter again\n");
           goto ag; 
       }

   x = factors(a1);

   if(x == 1)
       printf("%d is a perfect number\n", a1);
   else
       printf("%d is not a perfect number", a1);

   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

NASM program:

```
segment .text
global _factors

_factors: 

push ebp                    ; create stack frame
mov ebp, esp                ; save stack
mov eax, [ebp + 8]          ; first parameter

mov ebx, 00000001           ; initialize ebx to 1. ebx is the countere
mov ecx, eax                ; more eax to ecx in order to preserve the number

agn:
cmp ebx, ecx                ; check if the counter is equal to the number
je done

mov eax, ecx
xor dx, dx
div bx
inc ebx
cmp dx, 0
jne agn

mov word [fact], ax

lea dx, [fact]
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

jmp agn 

done:


leave
ret

section .data

fact times 5 db "$"
sum  times 5 db "$"
```

Comment: Using `int 21h` is certainly a problem.

Comment: `int 21h` is part of the previous 2 lines to print what's inside [fact] :)

Comment: `int 21h` only works in dos. I don't think you are using dos. In windows, linux or mac, that will crash.

Comment: `int 21h` is a call to MS-DOS. Do you produce a MS-DOS program?

Comment: Is this running under DOS or a DOS emulator? Or what system are you running on? `INT 21h` with `AH = 9` is a DOS software interrupt to print the *string (ASCII), terminated by `$`* pointed to by `DS:DX` to the standard output. You're just pointing to a number in memory. That's not going to work the way you think.

Comment: is there any other way to print the contents of [fact]?

Comment: We're using command prompt to compile and run the C program, and DOSBox to compile the .asm file.

Comment: To use `INT 21h` with `AH = 9` you need to convert your number to ASCII before you can print it. Alternatively, you could link to `printf` in the C library and [call `printf` from assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14169140/asm-call-printf).

Comment: _We're using command prompt to compile and run the C program, and DOSBox to compile the .asm file._ makes no sense to me. Can you edit your question and include operating system and commands used?

Comment: @jester at command prompt we type `gcc  -m32 -c <filename>.c` / `gcc -m32 <filename>.o <filename>.o -o <outputfile>.exe`. for the DOSBox we type the command `nasm -fwin32 -o <filename>.o <filename>.asm`

Comment: That looks like linux and no sign of dosbox. Please **edit your question** with this information. I don't see why you'd need dosbox for nasm, are you sure that's dosbox??? I don't think nasm even has a dos version. (It can produce code for dos, sure, but you can't run it under dos.)

Comment: DOSBox is an emulator for a 32-bit command prompt haha. we have 64-bit systems therefore we use this emulator.

Comment: @Jester: (BTW) There exists a DOS version of NASM: http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.11.09rc1/dos/. I don't know whether this version understands `-fwin32`.

Comment: @rkhb haha ... I also didn't notice he was using `-f win32` ... so I am totally confused now.

Comment: @Jester: Well, I just tried it :-) The DOS Version of NASM runs in DOSBox and can produce `-fwin32` files which can be linked at least with CYGWIN-GCC.

Comment: In any case, `-fwin32` does conflict with `int 21h` doesn't it?

Comment: @Jester: Of course! Also, it's a little insane using DOSBox to produce Windows files. I guess the OP don't use the program we all know as "DOSBox".

Comment: the call to `getchar()` will not pause the code.  Rather it will read the <newline> left in the input stream from the call to `scanf()` and not stop/pause.  The code needs to read the input stream until a '\n' or EOF is encountered, then have the final call to `getchar()`

Comment: the posted code fails to inform the user of the `valid` range of input values, so the user could be entering numbers forever.   What about negative numbers?  Perhaps the scanf() format specifier should be "%u"  or perhaps even "%hu" and `int a1` should be: `unsigned short a1`

Comment: Voting to close as why code not working. Please produce minimal examples.